# Error when translating content in DNN 2sxc module

Tags: localization, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a site with localization and using the 2sxc module but when i try to translate some of the content I get this error:

```
Had an error talking to the server (status 400).
Message: Bad Request
Detail: found languages in save which are not available in environment - used has 1 target has 1 used-list: 'en-ca'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that it's enabled both on DNN and 2sxc (in the apps-management dialog)

Comment: That did the trick. A minor suggestion would be that localization options wouldn't be available/visible unless both were enabled.